# DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE is not printing inside function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm running below code snippet, where dbms_ouput is not printing anything and just showing function compiled successfully in SQL Developer.

```
set serveroutput on size 30000;
create or replace function check_status (p_user_name in varchar2) return number is
begin
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Yoo');
end;
/
```

where below code snippet is printing. I wounder why its not printing inside function.

```
set serveroutput on size 30000;
begin
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Yoo');
end;
/
```

Comment: Did you only create the function or did you call it too? IN what you've shown, the code in the function is only compiled, it isn't executed - and the output won't be produced until it is executed, by calling the function.You need to have `set serveroutput on` before calling the function too. But as there is no `return` in the function, it will error at runtime anyway...

Comment: In your first snippet you create a function but never call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *compiled* the function, but you haven't *called* it. The code in the function will only be run when the function is called, so it is correct for it to not show any output at compile time.

Your function also needs to return a value; at the moment calling it would get:

```
select check_status('test') from dual;

ORA-06503: PL/SQL: Function returned without value
ORA-06512: at "MYSCHEMA.CHECK_STATUS", line 4

Yoo
```

which does show the output, but also errors.

So your function needs to return something:

```
create or replace function check_status (p_user_name in varchar2) return number is
begin
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Yoo');
  return 42;
end;
/

Function CHECK_STATUS compiled

select check_status('test') from dual;

CHECK_STATUS('TEST')
--------------------
                  42

Yoo
```

Also note that anyone calling the function will only see that `Yoo` if they have enabled output in their session or client. As you can't control that you shouldn't rely on it. It's mostly useful for debugging.